# Does lock file when using flock need to be global

Tags: python, bash, cron

I am setting up cron job for single instance.
Does the lock below need to be global? I believe so, in order that it stays in scope until the program finishes. Or at least outside of try/except block. Also, return values should be positive from Python? Seems -2 returns 254 on echo $? in bash.

```
import time, fcntl, sys

LOCK_FILE = '/tmp/test_flock.lock'
lock = None    
def do_wait():
    print ('waiting N sec')
    time.sleep(3)

def main(argv=None):
    try:
        global lock        
        lock = open(LOCK_FILE,'w')
        fcntl.flock(lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        print ("got flock")
    except IOError as err:
        print ("Could not obtain lock file")
        return -2

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    try:
        print ('entering main')
        print ('waiting')
#        raise ValueError("Error raised")
        do_wait()
        print ('done')
    except Exception as err:
        print ("Exception in main")
        return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

*Seems -2 returns 254 on echo $? in bash.*

The Bash is interpreting the -2 as 254 probably due to how it handles negative numbers which *I believe* is by returning 8-bit unsigned integers.

**Soln:** Use a postive integer number > 0 but < 256.  Bash will see a return code > 0 as an error.

*Does the lock below need to be global? I believe so, in order that it stays in scope until the program finishes.*

**Ans:** If there are no other conflicts with locking the file than I would say that the global lock is fine.